# Is there a specific language that the Phantasy Star series used as the basis for the naming of its techniques (spells)?

Tags: phantasy-star-4

Phantasy Star is a science fantasy jrpg series. After the second game the  “magic” was largely referred to as Techniques.

The naming scheme for [Techniques](http://phantasystar.wikia.com/wiki/Techniques) are what really sets them a part from the names commonly given to spells.

I was wondering what language or languages that the names where drawn from.